# SQL loader successfully loaded but returns fatal error

Tags: vb.net, oracle11g, sql-loader

I have run the following code in Windows 7 with Oracle client 11g installed. The SQL Loader log file indicates 10 rows successfully loaded, but the exit code returns 4 - fatal error on some machines. What exactly is the problem? Please advise.

```
Public Shared Function RunSQLLoader(ByVal intImportID As Integer, ByVal strFilePath As String) As Boolean
        Dim wsh As Object = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean = True
        Dim windowStyle As Integer = 0
        Dim exitCode As Integer

        exitCode = wsh.Run("sqlldr control=\\server\folder\upload.ctl data=\\server\folder\file.txt log=server\folder\file.log", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)

        If exitCode = 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            ExecuteError(intImportID, "SQL Loader Command Failure", "Fail to upload " & strFilePath & " with an exit code: " & exitCode)
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: What you can find in file.log?

Comment: Table DATA_IMPORT:
  10 Rows successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.


Space allocated for bind array:                 253944 bytes(36 rows)
Read   buffer bytes: 1048576

Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records read:            10
Total logical records rejected:         0
Total logical records discarded:        0

Comment: Does system log file / event viewer tell something?